# ¿Cómo se llama la Tabla que guarda los tipos de documento compra en SAP?

Tags: sap

Las tablas `EKKO` y `EBAN` en SAP tienen el campo Tipo documento compra (`BSTYP`) con elemento de datos `EBSTYP` y `BSTYP` respectivamente. ¿En qué tabla(s) se guardan los tipos documento?

Entré al dominio del campo en cada tabla y en ambos me muestra una lista de tipos de documento una más grande que otra, pero los tipos son similares.

Les adjunto una captura de ambos (`EKKO` y `EBAN` respectivamente).

[image: Tipos de documento - EKKO]

[image: Tipos de documento -EBAN]

Comment: La verdad no conozco SAP, pero en esta [página](http://www.tcodesearch.com/sap-tables/search?q=document+type) hay algunas tablas o puedes buscar `sap table doc types` en Google a ver qué obtienes. Consulta la documentación de SAP.

Answer (score 1):

Buenas,

Los tipos para esos campos no se guardan en ninguna tabla de mantenimiento, son entradas de valores fijos definidos en el Dominio, como se puede ver en tu imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que te ayude. Saludos.